# How do I get solr to return results from all indicies?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am starting to integrate with Solr and have run across what I perceive as an issue. I uploaded a simple spreadsheet using the java API (here is an exert:

```
 - Document, id,          value
 - Excel3,   name,        steelers
 - Excel3,   subject,     pirates
 - Excel3,   description, penguins
 - Excel3,   comments,    panthers
 - Excel3,   author,      panthers
```

)

Using this I used the first column as the "document name", second column as the field in the document to index, and the third column as the indexed data. All of these fields already existed in schema.xml, but here is how they are set up:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

now here is where my problem comes into play. I run a search for say steelers, and it comes back fine, but if I look for penguins, or many of the other fields, it does not pull back any results. However if I do description:penguins, the result pulls back as expected.

Can anyone please help me understand why the part before the : is required for some fields, but not others?

example searches:
solr/select?indent=on&q=penguins&wt=xml ----Doesn't return any results

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="q">penguins</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

solr/select?indent=on&q=description:penguins&wt=xml

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">18</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="q">description:penguins</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="author">panthers</str>
            <str name="comments">panthers</str>
            <str name="description">penguins</str>
            <str name="id">Excel3</str>
            <str name="name">steelers</str>
            <str name="subject">pirates</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

Comment: I believe the default query parser only searches one field.  Try dismax.  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMax  Try `solr/select?indent=on&q=description:penguins&wt=xml&defType=dismax`

Comment: Frank, I looked in the schema file, and am using the edismax query parser. with the query above, it does not return anything, but the query I provided did return results. (I am looking to not have to use description: and search only one field, but search all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default query parser will query the default field, which can be specified in the *schema.xml* as seen here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Default_Search_Field

I think @Frank Famer's comment about using the DisMax parser is a real solution to this problem.  That said, here are two work-arounds I've seen in practice:

1.Create an additional copyField that is indexed, not stored, that contains the values from all the fields you want to search and then specify that field as the default.  It would look something like this in your *schema.xml* file.

```
<field name="myhugedefaultfield" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="name" dest="myhugedefaultfield"/>
<copyField source="subject" dest="myhugedefaultfield"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="myhugedefaultfield"/>

<defaultSearchField>myhugedefaultfield</defaultSearchField>
```

2.Alter the user edited syntax and turn the query for **penguins** into a query for **(name:penguins) OR (subject:penguins) OR (description:penguins)**.